# Java, Oracle, Tomcat. Unable to read from an InputStream, connection closed

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I am currently trying to configure my Java dev environment. The application is locally deployed on tomcat 5.5.36 and connects to a remote oracle database. I am able to run the locally deployed version of the app and connect to the (remote) oracle database. Everything works fine in the app until I try to read an InputStream (populated from a resultset), at this point an exception is thrown stating that the database connection is closed. Now this does not occur on the currently deployed live app only in my development environment (locally deployed version using tomcat 5.5.36 connecting to remote oracle database.) I am pretty sure this is configuration but I am not sure what.

Comment: Without your code, no one can help you.

Comment: It would be a rather large amount of code to post all the many many layers involved in this. I am pretty sure this has its roots in some sort of connection pooling problems when deployed in tomcat as opposed to the live oracle app server.